# Unable to build maven project using command line

Tags: maven

I'm trying to build maven project using command line

```
c:\data\maven-demo\maven-test-project\Java>mvn test
```

[here](https://github.com/vitalliuss/helloci/tree/master/Java)

what I have in c:\data\maven-demo\maven-test-project\Java

I have such error:

```
[WARNING] File encoding has not been set, using platform encoding Cp1252, i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] Compiling 1 source file to c:\data\maven-demo\maven-test-project\Java\target\test-classes
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:3.0.0-M1:test (default-test) @ hello-ci ---
[INFO]
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------
[INFO]  T E S T S
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Running com.github.vitalliuss.helloci.AppTest
[ERROR] Tests run: 5, Failures: 1, Errors: 0, Skipped: 1, Time elapsed: 0.031 s <<< FAILURE! - in com.github.vitalliuss.helloci.AppTest
[ERROR] testShouldBeFailed(com.github.vitalliuss.helloci.AppTest)  Time elapsed: 0.006 s  <<< FAILURE!
java.lang.AssertionError
        at com.github.vitalliuss.helloci.AppTest.testShouldBeFailed(AppTest.java:21)

[INFO]
[INFO] Results:
[INFO]
[ERROR] Failures:
[ERROR]   AppTest.testShouldBeFailed:21
[INFO]
[ERROR] Tests run: 5, Failures: 1, Errors: 0, Skipped: 1
[INFO]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  2.382 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2020-08-06T16:40:02+03:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:3.0.0-M1:test (default-test) on project hello-ci: There are test failures.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] Please refer to c:\data\maven-demo\maven-test-project\Java\target\surefire-reports for the individual test results.
[ERROR] Please refer to dump files (if any exist) [date].dump, [date]-jvmRun[N].dump and [date].dumpstream.
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException
```

I use maven C:\apache-maven-3.6.3
use C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-13.0.1

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the unit tests are failed. The unit test `AppTest.testShouldBeFailed` is failed so the build won't pass.

Quick fix, you can simply change `assertTrue(false);` with `assertTrue(true);`

Comment: or (if just building is the goal), run `mvn compile` or `mvn install -DskipTests`

Comment: Yes it helps. Thanks